# SSH from A through B to C, using private key on B

Tags: linux, ssh, firewall, bash, proxy

I'm looking for a simple way to SSH from my local machine, A, through a proxy, B, to a destination host, C. The private key that goes with the public key on C is on B, and I can't put that key on my local machine. Any tips?

Also, I'd like to be able to do this using ~/.ssh/config.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to ssh from A to B, and then SSH to C ? Or is proxy a true pass-thru situation?

Comment: I want to ssh from A to C, passing through B. My answer below works for the passing through part, but it still tries to look for the IdentityFile on my local computer instead of on B, the pass-through host.

Comment: Without nc you can use ssh parameter inside ProxyCommand -W %h:%p

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Schematic:

```
    ssh       ssh
A ------> B ------> C
    ^          ^
 using A's   using B's
 ssh key     ssh key
```

Preconditions:

- `A` is running ssh-agent;
- `A` can access `B`;
- `B` can access `C`;
- `A`'s ssh public key is present in `B:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- `B`'s ssh public key is present in `C:~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

In `~/.ssh/config` on `A`, add

```
Host C
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' B 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

If your ssh private key on B is in a nonstandard location, add its path after `ssh-add`.

You should now be able to access `C` from `A`:

```
A$ ssh C
C$
```

Comment: This works flawlessly.

Comment: Starting with openssh v.7.3, you can just use `ProxyJump B`.  source: [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump)

Comment: Can this be defined such that:

Host user1@c
    ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' user2@B 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'

Comment: How would the solution change if machine B doesn't have `nc`?

Comment: @DrewVS `ProxyJump B` doesn't seem to work if the private key for C is only present on B. Is there some way to do that as well?

Comment: @DrewVS Ok, one needs to add `ForwardAgent yes` *before* the `ProxyJump` command.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding ProxyJump, -J and -W I don't think we can get ride of nc for this specific use-case. They allow to forward traffic in various ways, but here we need to fully login on the machine to leverage its private key (with ssh-add), the only way I could get it to work is through nc (same as per the accepted answer). I would love to be proven wrong though.

Comment: This was the only solution for the particular case for me. All other solutions require gateway root credentials

Comment: I expect this probably works if the private key does not have a passphrase, but with a passphrase I do not get prompted for a passphrase and I get "Bad passphrase, try again".  Using -t does not help.  It is possible to add the key from B and ssh to C in two steps (ssh -A -t B ssh-add; ssh -J B C), though this (perhaps undesirably) adds the key from B to the agent on A.

Comment: This worked for me after a bit, I did have to add a `User` inside the  `C` config, as it was using my `A` user (whoami).

Comment: I also had to start `ssh-agent` on `B` as `ssh-add` needs that otherwise I got "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20403535/292408

Comment: Also, my key was in the standard location ~/.ssh/ but it was not named the standard id_rsa, so I did have to specify that, eg. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/special-key-name`.

Comment: I added the comment above about needing `ssh-agent` on `B` to the answer as an edit.

Comment: @ElijahLynn It is not necessary to run `ssh-agent` on `B`, only `sshd`.

Comment: Hrm, I get this error if I don't https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent/20403535#20403535, even then I have a hard time getting that to work consistently. Wonder what is up with that.

Comment: This solution forwards all ssh connections right? How to forward the agent only for the specific server?

Comment: Simply not true : https://serverfault.com/questions/724721/ssh-config-proxycommand-asks-for-public-key

Comment: Can anyone answer how to do the same without nc ?

Comment: Anyone know how to do this without ssh-add?

Comment: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Comment: Another option (replace \n with newlines because SO comments dont support line breaks):

Host C\n
  Hostname B\n
  RemoteCommand ssh %n\n
  RequestTTY yes

Comment: A question on Stack Overflow motivated by the usage of single-quotes here, which does does not work for the SO asker: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75735262/11107541

Answer (score 42):

Check if following is working.

```
ssh -t B ssh C
```

Use following command if you want to use key stored on B.

```
ssh -t B ssh -i /path/to/identity_on_B C
```

Here we are specifying command i.e `ssh -i /path/to/identity_on_B C` to be executed on B instead of a login shell.

Comment: This works but it does not pick up the IdentityFile from B. It still looks on A.

Comment: @DrewVS I have updated the answer. Please check if it is working for you.

Comment: Sachin, very clever. That worked perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: @DrewVS glad to hear that it worked for you. so please accept the answer.

Comment: However, it looks like this does not work with password protected rsa keys. The password input is hidden, forcing the user to have to add the key to their ssh-key in order for this approach to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not getting your problem. Even if the key is passphrase protected, it is working for me.

Comment: That is likely because the key is in your ssh-agent. If you try running 'ssh-add -D' first, that will clear your ssh-agent. Then, if you try the above again, instead of being prompted for the password to the identity key, it hangs. It looks like the password input is in another tty. 

Otherwise your solution is great.

Comment: @DrewVS Actually I am not using ssh-agent.

Comment: Sachin, you are right! My mistake, not sure what I did wrong before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FML, this works from the command line, but not when set up in a .ssh/config file using the ProxyCommand. I'm stuck. The whole idea here is to have all my id_rsa keys in a central location, and use the .ssh/config to create the shortcuts to ssh through this central box

Comment: @SachinDivekar I get very low speeds with commands like `cat bigfile >/dev/null`. What is `-t` doing under the hood - redirecting all stdio from C to B?

Answer (score 12):

I've worked this out now. Here is the solution, which is rather straightforward. I should have seen it sooner:

~/.ssh/config:

```
Host B
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  User myuser
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_key
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket/master-%l-%r@%h:%p

Host C.*
  User customer_username
  Port customer_port
  IdentityFile remote/path/to/ssh/key
  ForwardAgent yes
  ProxyCommand ssh accessable.server nc %h %p

Host C.server-1
  HostName 2.3.4.5
```

'B' is the Proxy server that you are jumping through. It should be configured as you normally would configure access to a server.

'C' is the destination host. It needs to be configured to use 'B' in the connection process. The identity file in 'C' is the path to the ssh-key on 'B'. The ProxyCommand uses Netcat to open the connection to 'C' from 'B'. Netcat, or nc, will need to be installed on 'B'.

NOTE1: For this to work, you need to copy the identity file of B (usually ~/.ssh/rd_isa) to A. I usually change its name to rd_isa_B.

NOTE2: This solution also works for scp.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: I spoke too soon. This solution does not see to work. The key had been loaded in the ssh-agent, so I thought it was working. 

In the above, the key for C still needs to be on A, not B.

Comment: This is fantastic. Exactly what I was looking for -- to be able to proxy through a jumpbox using keys locally (to avoid the keys proliferating on the intermediate)

Answer (score 7):

[Snowball's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/701884/133019) helped a lot. However, I made some modifications to the command and wanted to explain how it works.
Given this situation:

```
    ssh        ssh
A -------> B -------> C
     ^          ^
  using A's  using B's
  ssh key    ssh key
```

Modify your `~/.ssh/config` file and add the host `B` through which you want to jump, just how you would normally configure a host:

```
Host B
 User myusername
 HostName b.mycompany.com
```

Then you add the host `C` that you want to end up on:

```
Host C
 User myusername
 HostName c.intranet.mycompany.com
 ProxyCommand ssh -T -q -o 'ForwardAgent yes' B 'ssh-add -t 1 && nc %h %p'
```

Note the `ProxyCommand`, where:

- `ssh -T -q` indicates that it should not allocate a pseudo-TTY (`-T`) and be quiet (`-q`);
- once on the jump host `B`, we add the key to the SSH keys of `A` through `ssh-add`;
- which only works because we forwarded the SSH agent using `-o 'ForwardAgent yes'`.
- `ssh-add -t 1` indicates that I want the key to be added only for the 1 second needed to authenticate to the final host C;
- and finally, `nc %h %p` initiates a `netcat` connection to the final host `%h` at port `%p` (both which will be filled out by SSH based on the information in the `~/.ssh/config` file).

If you need to specify a custom key on `B` to use, you can do that by modifying the `ssh-add` part:

```
Host C
 User myusername
 HostName c.intranet.mycompany.com
 ProxyCommand ssh -T -q -o 'ForwardAgent yes' B 'ssh-add -t 1 ~/.ssh/mykey && nc %h %p'
```

Comment: if host B and C uses different key file, Can this be done by placing both the key files in the local system(Host A)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple script to basically list my ssh keys on the remote instance, and then add the one I selected to my local ssh agent. This is not very clean, but allows me to keep all keys on a remote location rather than locally.

Here's the script if anyone is interested:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require "rubygems"
require "fileutils"

# Get key list
key_list = (`ssh jumpbox "cd ~/.ssh/ ; ls id_rsa*" | sed 's/id_rsa_/  /g' | sed     's/id_rsa//g'`)
puts ' '
puts 'Available customer keys:'
puts key_list

# Get customer name input
puts ' '
puts 'Enter customer name: '
customer_name = gets.chomp

# Add key to ssh-agent
key_name = "~/.ssh/id_rsa_#{customer_name}"
puts ' '
puts "Adding #{key_name} to local ssh-agent"
`ssh jumpbox "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_#{customer_name}"`
exit 0
```

Comment: I think the adding of a key can be treated as idempotent thereby eliminating the need for get key list.

Comment: You should accept http://serverfault.com/a/701884/127993 which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
target_host=10.121.77.16
target_port=22
target_user=vagrant

bastion_user=yourusername
bastion_host=10.23.85.245
bastion_port=32780

scp -P $target_port -o ProxyCommand="ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' $bastion_user@$bastion_host -p $bastion_port 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/*.rsa && nc %h %p'" /tmp/x.txt $target_user@$target_host:/tmp/
```

Answer (score 1):

To do:

`ssh someuser@IP_D`

such that

`A -> B-> C -> D` where A is the host you are on,

edit your local ~/.ssh/config like so:

```
Host IP_D
  ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' userX@IP_C 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
Host IP_C
  ProxyCommand ssh -o 'ForwardAgent yes' userY@IP_B 'ssh-add && nc %h %p'
```

This answer is based on the chosen answer. I had to figure out how various users fit in to the whole scenario.

This works for me. HTH.