# RDP-from-a-through-b-to-c in one step

Tags: linux, windows, rdp

Computer A can Reach Computer B

Computer B can reach Computer C

Here is an answer from someone that wanted to connect straight to computer C from computer a using ssh:
[SSH from A through B to C, using private key on B](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b)

I have been using the above answer for some time to access a network that only allows traffic from a specific network over ssh, However I cannot figure out a way to do this Using a Windows and Remote Desktop Protocol, And I reluctantly need to manually RDP from A to B and then manually RDP from B to C.

It gets real boring doing this multiple times a day.

Is there anyway to set up B (either a linux or windows box) such that I can rdp through it(or bounce) straight to C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the RDP port is the standard 3389, you can simply use

```
ssh -L 3389:c.example.com:3389 user@b.example.com
```

from system A and then point the RDP client to `localhost:3389`. If you are running another RDP server on A, you would need to change the ports, e.g.

```
ssh -L 13389:c.example.com:3389 user@b.example.com
```

and connect to `localhost:13389`.

What happens here is that all traffic you send to `localhost:3389` is tunneled via SSH to B and from there send to host C, appearing as it came from host B.