# SSH from A through B, C to D using private key on B to access C and D

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I'm looking for a way to access to a server (*D*) through 2 proxy (*B* and *C*) using SSH keys stored on the first proxy (*B*). My computer (*A*) isn't allowed to save the key.

I understand the way to access to C using the key on *B* with an ssh `config` file (cf [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/701884/365828)):

```
Host C
    ProxyCommand ssh -T -q -o 'ForwardAgent yes' B 'ssh-add -t 1 ~/.ssh/mykey && nc %h %p'
```

But from this point I can't use *C* as a proxy using the same method because *C* doesn't know the key to access to *D*. Only *B* does.

```
A ------------> B ------------> C ------------> D
  key 1 from A    key 2 from B    key 3 from B
```

Is there any existing ssh property allowing to perform this action.

Thanks!

Comment: ssh-copyid is I think what you looking for

Comment: You do realize that adding a remote key to your local agent.. *equals* downloading the key? The only way you could be using a remote key locally without copying it.. is to forward the agent connection the other way around, and keep all signature work on the machine with the key.