# Ansible SSH From A -> B -> C using SSH Config on B

Tags: ssh, ansible

There is a very similar question to what I'm asking at [SSH from A through B to C, using private key on B](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b)

That question does have a solution that works for me, which is

`ssh -t B ssh C`

However I've failed to convert this to something usable by Ansible. When I try it complains about invalid syntax. This is what I tried

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-t -i ~/.ssh/mykey admin@B ssh'
```

Which gives me "syntax error near unexpected token". I could persist with this, but I get the impression that Ansible might have some more serious issues with hijacking the SSH command like this.

I've also asked a similar question on StackOverflow with https://stackoverflow.com/q/73975618/1196369 - but without success.

I have managed to get the connection working using the `-J B` (ProxyJump) or `ProxyCommand` options, however both of these seem to skip the SSH configuration on B. I've added configuration to `~/.ssh/config` on B so that it will use a reverse tunnel when connecting to C. Using `ssh -t B ssh C` picks up this config and the reverse tunnel is created, but using ProxyJump or ProxyCommand does not create the reverse tunnel.

If the reverse tunnel is not created then C cannot access the internet, and this is required for the Ansible playbook I'd like to run.

I can combine `-R` for the reverse tunnel in the original command, and that works... but it means the tunnel is created from `C -> A -> B` and not `C -> B` as I would like. This looks something like:

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-J admin@B'
ansible_ssh_extra_args='-R 3129:B:3128'
```

So my main question is how can I use `ProxyJump` (-J) in combination with `RemoteForward` (-R) on Ansible where the reverse tunnel is created from the proxy server, and *not* the host?

Comment: When using jumphost you don't need a config on B. All the configuration belongs to A, the node where Ansbile is running. Only public keys need to be distributed.

Comment: Hi Nikita, yeah - jumphost works fine on it's own, but I'd like to use a reverse tunnel when connecting from B -> C and I'm not sure how I can do this (except when I manually SSH into B, then use `-R` to ssh to C)